# How to delete old emails when a new email with the same subject is being received

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I'm Having trouble deleting Emails with same subject line but keeping the newly received Email on Outlook-vba

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: show your work?

Comment: Have you started coding yet? What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am relatively new to Outlook VBA and I'm not yet familiar with the objects and methods of the library. So the short answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with *[**Dictionary Object**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx)* to Store `Items.Subject` while you measure the received `Item.ReceivedTime` with `Item.ReceivedTime` in your `Inbox.Items`

---

> *<sub>**[Dictionary in VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx)** is a collection-object: 
>   you can store all kinds of things in it: numbers, texts, dates, arrays, ranges, variables and objects, Every item in a Dictionary gets its own unique key and 
>   With that key you can get direct access to the item (reading/writing).</sub>*

---

Now to Automate the process - Try working with *[Application.Startup Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869298.aspx)* And *[Items_ItemAdd Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx)*

> *<sub>**[Items.ItemAdd Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx)** Occurs when one or more Items are added to the specified collection. This event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once.</sub>*

---

*Code Example*

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        RemoveDupEmails Item ' call sub
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RemoveDupEmails(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim DupItem As Object
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim i As Long

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items

    Debug.Print Item.ReceivedTime ' Immediate Window

    Set DupItem = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set Items = Inbox.Items

    Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
        If TypeOf Items(i) Is MailItem Then
            Set Item = Items(i)

            If Item.ReceivedTime >= Items(i).ReceivedTime Then

                If DupItem.Exists(Item.Subject) Then
                    Debug.Print Item.Subject ' Immediate Window
                    'Item.Delete ' UnComment to delete Item
                Else
                    DupItem.Add Item.Subject, 0
                End If

            End If

        End If
    Next i

    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set DupItem = Nothing
    Set Items = Nothing
End Sub
```

---